# populate a form with a bookmarklet doesn't work in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet that just does some simple form input population but the angular form is still in an invalid state. Like nothing was ever changed.

I tried calling `el.onchange()` but that doesn't seem to do anything.

```
javascript:populate();

function populate(){
    var name = document.querySelector('input[name=name]');

    name.value = 'Fred';

    name.click();
    name.onchange();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I already have jQuery loaded, I was able to fix the issue by triggering the `input` event.

```
$('input[ng-model]').trigger('input');
```

Answer (score 0):

I used something similar to the code below to create my bookmarklet.
Couple of things to consider.

- Write your function (see example below)
- Before creating your bookmarklet, test your function in the chrome console
- Function tested, now remove the endlines (e.g. "replace all" in intellij (with regex enabled), replace "\n" with ""
- create a new bookmark in the browser
- edit the url, the url should begin with **"javascript:"**, paste your one line url after that... you'll end up with something like **"javascript:(function(){..."** etc...

```js
//nb: This function is not written to work in this page

(function () {
 //get the scope object for your controller
 var sc=angular.element("[ng-controller=myController]").scope();
 
 //grab your model
 var m=sc.mymodel;
 
 //some 'dodgy' date strings :)
 var today=new Date();
 var todayAsString=today.toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
 today.setDate(today.getDate()-183);
 var sixMonthsAgoStr=today.toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
 today.setDate(today.getDate()+365);
 var sixMonthsLaterStr=today.toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
 
 //pick a random oz state
 var states=["WA", "VIC","SA", "NT","NSW", "ACT", "QLD"];
 var ozState=states[Math.floor(Math.random()*(6)+1)];
 
 //update the model with some semi random values 
 m.actionDate=todayAsString;
 m.ausstralianState=ozState;
 m.streetNum=Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
 m.ID="CR" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
 m.manufactureYear="" + Math.floor(Math.random()*(2016-1960+1)+1960); //approx... between 1960 and 2016... 
 m.endDate=sixMonthsLaterStr;
 m.startDate=sixMonthsAgoStr;
 
 //MUST call $scope.apply() at the end.
 sc.$apply();
})();
```